# Can a Trigger be written around a select statement?

Tags: mysql

can a trigger be applied on this MySQL code?

```
SELECT name, cost AS originalCost, whenacquired, monthsDepreciated, monthlyDepreciation, 
       monthsDepreciated * monthlyDepreciation AS totalDepreciation,
       cost - monthsDepreciated * monthlyDepreciation AS depreciatedValue
FROM (
    SELECT name, 
           cost,
           whenacquired, 
           (YEAR(NOW())*12 + Month(NOW())) - ( YEAR(whenacquired)*12 + Month(whenacquired)) AS monthsDepreciated,
           cost / ( life * 12 ) AS monthlyDepreciation
    FROM assets
    ) AS X
ORDER BY whenacquired;
```

If yes suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: What would be the purpose of the trigger? To log the data that was returned? To *change* the data that was returned? Something else?

Comment: Trigger can be defined for events that changing data, i.e. `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE`

Comment: I doubt you need a trigger for a SELECT.Whats your purpose?

Comment: the purpose is to automatically calculate anytime an asset is entered and also when an update is done on the cost,life etc of an asset, it should affect the output

Comment: so for example if i enter the cost, life and depreciatedValue, it should compute and give me the monthsDepreciated,monthlyDepreciation, and the AccDepreciation .

Comment: and anytime an update is done on any of the inserted values, it should affect the output

Comment: No you can't put a trigger on a select. Yopu write the select to do the calculation you want done. You run the select when you need the information and it will get what is currently in the database.